Can’t override the color of a button
Can’t override the color of the Vutify button

<template>
  <v-app-bar app>
    <v-toolbar-title>Найти репетитора</v-toolbar-title>
    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
<v-btn text to="/">Main</v-btn>
<v-btn text to="/coaches">Coaches</v-btn>
<v-btn text to="/register">Register</v-btn>
  </v-app-bar>
</template>

<style>
.v-btn {
        cursor: pointer; 
        background-color: transparent !important; 
        color: white;
   }
</style>>

When I hover over the button, it’s not clear where the hover comes from and it overlaps the text of the button. how can I fix this error?
Plugin:
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify';
import * as components from 'vuetify/components';
import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives';

const vuetify = createVuetify({
  components,
  directives,
});

export default vuetify;

main.js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import './style.css'
import App from './App.vue'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify';

createApp(App)
  .use(vuetify)
  .mount('#app');


the color only appears when you hover over the button?  VBtn hover style should be from the span with class v-btn__overlay.  it's not clear what you've done to create the color with full opacity as that's not the default behavior, but you can use that class I mentioned to override it.

Sorry, I didn't get what you meant. Are you trying to disable the hover effect when hovering the button?

If you want a button with transparent background:
<v-btn variant="text">Main</v-btn>

The issue in your code is that you use text prop which has become in variant="text" in Vuetify 3.
